# jQuery call on a <div> tag (or any HTML element) - is looping implied?

Tags: jquery

I'm learning jQuery and had a question about a method call on an HTML element.  In this case it's a `<div>` tag.

The jQuery call goes like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
 $('.someClass').myMethod({
  value1: 'sometext',
  value2: 'someothertext'
  });
 });

</script>
```

The `<div>` tag has a CSS class of 'someClass', as you can see below:

```
<div class="someClass" style="display: none;">
<div id="my-content">
<img id="enter" alt="Logo" src="images/logo.png">
</div>
</div>
```

My question is, what's happening with that method call in jQuery?  Is it looping over all elements contained within the `<div class='someClass'/>` and calling myMethod on all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It completely depends on the plugin implementation.

`$('.someClass')` will select all the elements with calss `.someClass` now its the plugin which will use this set and apply its logic on the set of matched elements or just a single element.

Answer (score 2):

Your method call isn't looping over the *contents* of your `div`. It's looping over *all elements with the class* `someclass`. The "cascading" part of CSS will, however, apply the styles to all contained elements of your `div`.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it will call a jQuery method "myMethod" (which does not exist unless you wrote a plugin that implements it) on all elements matched, that is all elements having a CSS class "someClass".